# Конвертация типов данных

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, типы-данных, строки

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне превратить тип данных STR в html элемент для дальнейшего парсинга с помощью библиотеки BeautifulSoup. Вся проблема заключаетсяя в том при использовании метода Find, я использовал метод get и все данные которые выводятся принимают значение STR, но я в этом не уверен, может проблема в этом? Мне нужно использовать метод Find или Find_all, но после использования метода Get эти два поиска не применяются

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml') 
result = soup.find('tbody', id = "tbodyResult") 
refusalsDiv = result.find('div', class_="starsPopover").get('data-content')
```

После использования get('data-content'), данные принимают тип STR, и к ним не применяется метод Find из библиотеки BeautifulSoup

```html
<table class="GridView">
<tr><td colspan="2"><b>EMIR</b> - statistics for 30 days</td></tr>
<tr><td>Orders</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Refusals</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td>On time</td><td>100%</td></tr>
<tr><td>Late</td><td>0%</td></tr>
</table>
```

а выходе я получаю эти значения но не могу обратиться ни к одному тегу, и все данные выходят вместе с тегами как текстовая строка

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажити ваш код

Comment: Добавьте код и пример прямо в вопрос. В комментариях плохо с форматированием.